# How to set background colour of a cell in an XSLT template

Tags: xml, xslt, ms-word

I'm writing an XSLT template and would like to know how I can set the background colour of the cells in the word document that this XSLT creates.

Below is a section from the template where you can set the colour of the lines (not the background) using w:color="auto". I cant find anything on google or here on stack overflow.

What would be really useful is a reference site that lists all these tags, if anyone has a link I'd be really grateful

Thanks in advance

```
<w:tc>
    <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="2600" w:type="dxa"/>
        <w:tcBorders>
            <w:top w:val="single" w:sz="12" wx:bdrwidth="30" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
            <w:left w:val="single" w:sz="2" wx:bdrwidth="5" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
            <w:bottom w:val="single" w:sz="12" wx:bdrwidth="30" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
            <w:right w:val="single" w:sz="12" wx:bdrwidth="30" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
        </w:tcBorders>
        <w:vAlign w:val="center"/>
    </w:tcPr>
    <w:p>
    <w:pPr>
        <w:jc w:val="center"/>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:sz w:val="14"/>
            <w:sz-cs w:val="14"/>
        </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:sz w:val="14"/>
            <w:sz-cs w:val="14"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>Comments</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
</w:tc>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recomend you to use OpenXML SDK development tool which can be downloaded from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124). Just create a template from the editor (Microsoft Office Editor. Word or Excel). Apply a style and than open your file in OpenXML SDK where you can see how office applying styles.
Regards